# Sharepoint: list does not exist. Which list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

When I try to access the cache settings for my site at the url `http://my.site.com/site/_Layouts/areacachesettings.aspx` I get the error below.

There is nothing more in the url and I really have no idea which list is being mentioned here. The only one I can think of is **Cache Profiles** and that one is there when I check with Sharepoint Manager...

Any ideas?

-

> List does not exist
>
> The page you selected contains a list
>   that does not exist. It may have been
>   deleted by another user. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListsWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String
>   bstrListInternalName, Int32
>   dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32
>   dwServerTemplate, UInt32
>   dwGetListFlags, UInt32
>   dwListFilterFlags, Boolean
>   bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean
>   bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean
>   bGetSecurityData, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String
>   bstrListInternalName, Int32
>   dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32
>   dwServerTemplate, UInt32
>   dwGetListFlags, UInt32
>   dwListFilterFlags, Boolean
>   bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean
>   bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean
>   bGetSecurityData, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution at http://blogs.tamtam.nl/operational-services/2010/02/23/SiteCollectionOutputCacheListDoesNotExist.aspx .

In short the **Office Sharepoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** feature has to be deactivated and reactivated on the site collection to make this work again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the SharePoint logs. There are tons of information in there - sometimes too much :-). Check this article [SharePoint 2007 Log Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781179/sharepoint-2007-log-viewer)

Comment: Nothing in the logs more then the "List does not exist" message.

Answer (score 0):

Then the answer is "Pages" List.

Comment: Found a solution (see my own answer). Seems to be a Sharepoint bug.