# SharePoint Online Log Viewer

Tags: sharepoint, logging, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

In looking at the answers from [SharePoint 2007 Log Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781179/sharepoint-2007-log-viewer), it looks like all the viewers require either access to the server or access to Central Administration. We recently deployed a set of solution packages using [SharePoint](http://www.microsoft.com/online/sharepoint-online.aspx) [Online](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint-Online/Pages/default.aspx) and thus do not have access to either.

Is there a web based log viewer that can be deployed to a non-Central Administration SharePoint website?

Comment: Am surprised that SharePoint online doesn't provide access to the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the ULS logs are a pretty highly privileged function.  There is a whole bunch of stuff in there that could be construed as being very sensitive (database connect strings, identities of service accounts, etc).  It doesn't surprise me at all that you don't have access to that in SharePoint Online especially when you are most likely running in a multi-tenancy environment where there are lots of different customers all using the same hardware and thus all logging to the same ULS logs.

What bothers me is that they didn't seem to provide a way for Sandbox Solutions to easily log error or tracing statements.

Comment: We have a dedicated server. I can understand not exposing the logs in a shared environment, but was disappointed to find that dedicated was subject to the same rules.